# How to boot OSX into desktop from single mode?

Tags: macos, command-line, single-user

Is there any possibility to boot graphical mode once I'm in single mode (CMD+S on boot time) logged as root?

Related:

- http://www.mactalk.com.au/11/90219-boot-into-desktop-single-user-mode.html
- http://www.westwind.com/reference/os-x/commandline/single-user.html
- https://www.securemac.com/macosxsingleuser.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `exit` command will continue the startup process where it left off, leaving you in the normal graphical environment. But note that you will not be logged in as root, it'll take you to the normal login screen. If you want to log in as root in GUI mode, you'll need to set a root password (which you can do in single-user mode with the command `passwd root`).

Comment: Simply `passwd` also works